# Como receber dados do usuário e retornar valor de função usando flask?

Tags: python, flask

Eu tenho um projeto onde gostaria de aplicar uma função em python usando informações dadas pelo usuário e devolver o resultado da função para o html. Eu sei que normalmente se usa javascript para esses casos, mas minha função usa algumas funcionalidade do pandas e seria difícil escrever o mesmo código em javascript.

Ocorre que não sei como faço para acessar valores dados pelo usuário e nem como retornar o resultado da função para o html. O que tentei foi usar o comando:

```
<button action="{{ url_for('myfunction') }}">Mybutton</button>
```

Isso funcionou para a função, mas não consigo pegar o valor do usuário e nem retornar o resultado da função para o html.

Aqui um exemplo replicável do que tentei até agora:

arquivo python

```py
#app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def render_index():
    return render_template('index.html', name='')

@app.route('/result')
def upper_name(name):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name.upper())
```

arquivo html:

```html
#templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <p>Your upper case name is {{ name }}</p>
        <button action="{{ url_for('upper_name') }}">Upper</button> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note que esse exemplo carrega a página, permite que o usuário entre um nome, mas quando o botão Upper é aplicado, a página não é atualizada da forma desejada.

Como faço para acessar valores dados pelo usuário e retorna os valores da minha função para o html usando flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu "problema" não está bem no Python mas sim no HTML. Acontece que o atributo *action* não existe em `<button>` ([<button>: The Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)) e sim em `<form>`, então o teu formulário ficaria assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  ...
    <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="form_name" name="name"><br>
      <p>Your upper case name is {{ name }}</p>
      <button type="submit">Upper</button>
    </form>
  ...
```

Veja que o *action* foi colocado em `<form>` e `<button>` recebeu o tipo "submit" para indicar que ele deve submeter o formulário ao ser clicado. A adição do `method="post"` serve para que o navegador use o método HTTP **POST** ao invés do **GET** para enviar o formulário.

Quando você envia por **GET** os dados vão codificados na própria URL, tipo "/?name=fulano", agora imagine um formulário completo com nome, telefone, senha etc...

Mas há uma coisa que podem ser acertadas no Python já que você não precisa criar duas rotas se no final elas irão exibem o mesmo conteúdo:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name'].upper()
    else:
        name = ''

    return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

Veja que esta rota agora aceita tanto o método **GET** quanto o ***POST**.

Quando ela é acessada via **POST** (ou seja, ao receber os dados do formulário) o valor de "nome" é recuperado, o método `.upper()` usado para colocar a *string* em maiúsculas e o "index.html" rasterizado.

Caso contrário, que é o acesso via **GET** (o modo padrão), o "index.html" é rasterizado mas usando um valor vazio para "nome".

Agora uma dica, você pode colocar uma condição no "index.html":

```html
{% if name != "" %}
<p>Your upper case name is {{ name }}.</p>
{% endif %}
```

E assim só exibir esta mensagem caso realmente exista um nome a ser impresso.